# How does this lowercase expression works in bash

Tags: bash, scripts

I want to convert a vaiable value to lower case. To do this, I am doing following

```
lower_case_var=echo ${var,,}
```

Above expression works fine. However, I am wondering that how it works?

Comment: It does? That's amazing.

Comment: The `^` operator modifies the first character to uppercase, the `,` operator to lowercase. When using the double-form (`^^` and `,,`), all characters are converted. see [man bash](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man1/bash.1.html)

Comment: The above expression very likely does *not* do what you want - it sets `lower_case_var` equal to `echo` and *runs* the lower cased version of `$var` with `lower_case_var` in its context (and `lower_case_var` is *not* available to the rest of the script). Either do `lower_case_var="${var,,}"` or `lower_case_var="$(echo "${var,,}")"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Section *Parameter Expansion* (extract) from bash's manpage:

```
   ${parameter,,pattern}
          Case modification.   This  expansion  modifies  the  case  of
          alphabetic  characters in parameter.  The pattern is expanded
          to produce a pattern just as in pathname  expansion.   The  ^
          operator  converts  lowercase  letters  matching  pattern  to
          uppercase; the , operator converts matching uppercase letters
          to  lowercase.  The ^^ and ,, expansions convert each matched
          character in the expanded value; the ^ and , expansions match
          and  convert  only the first character in the expanded value.
          If pattern is omitted, it is treated like a ?, which  matches
          every  character.  If parameter is @ or *, the case modifica‐
          tion operation is applied to  each  positional  parameter  in
          turn,  and the expansion is the resultant list.  If parameter
          is an array variable subscripted with @ or *, the case  modi‐
          fication  operation is applied to each member of the array in
          turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.
```